# Can Java HashMap create deadlocks?

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap

I have a `HashMap` that many threads read and write to at the same time.

Can that cause a deadlock?

Answer (score 4):

Deadlocks only occur if you use multiple locks and don't lock/unlock them in the correct order. If you are only protecting your `HashMap` with one (correctly used) lock (or not at all), then deadlocks cannot occur.

Note that the standard `HashMap` is not itself protected in any way, so only your locking code (which you haven't posted) can cause a deadlock.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen `HashMap` go into endless loops  when it is concurrently modified. It is not related to deadlock (or livelock) but it is caused by traversing a corrupt data structure.

This especially happens when a bucket is converted into a TreeNode as the code which traverses trees does not protect itself from broken references.

You typically see then stacktraces where a thread is stuck in `putTreeVal` or similar places.

Comment: I found this helpful as a further explanation: https://www.programmersought.com/article/27715234177/

Answer (score 2):

The hashmap itself does not do any locking. Nevertheless, any correct code that reads and modifies the same map from multiple threads will have to use locks. Once locking enters the picture, there is potential for deadlocks.

Without knowing more about how many locks there are, and how they are used it is impossible to say for sure whether a deadlock is possible.

Answer (score 1):

A deadlock is when 2 actors are locking and waiting for resources each other.

Of course a deadlock may happened when using a HashMap. But the deadlock is made by your code which is using the HashMap.

Check your code, I beg the answer is in it.

Answer (score 1):

`HashMap` isn't thread-safe and doesn't do any locking. So, you wont get deadlocks, but then you might not get what you want either. As it turns out, you can end up in an infinite loop, but you'll probably not detect that in testing.

`java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap` is thread-safe and gives good performance. However, there is a lot more to to multithreading.

Comment: my rule of the thumb if you use: `ConcurrentMap` just like normal `Map` (i.e. only put/get/remove), there must be something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

A deadlock is not possible using an unadorned `HashMap`.  The `HashMap` class does no locking so there is not opportunity for deadlock.

However, if you used `Collections.synchronizedMap(...)` to wrap a `HashMap` and you used this in conjunction with other locking, you could get a deadlock ... if different threads acquired the locks on the objects in a different order.

And obviously, multiple threads accessing the same `HashMap` (which is not thread-safe) is hazardous.  Indeed, it *might* be possible for one thread to see an inconsistent state of a `HashMap` that causes it to go into an infinite loop; e.g. stuck in an apparent cycle in one of the hash chains.  This seems unlikely, but to be sure it was impossible you'd need to do a thorough analysis of the code, taking account of memory anomalies caused by multiple threads hitting the data structure without synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

`HashMap` is not synchronized, so yes, you will probably get in trouble. I'm not sure if deadlock specifically - I suppose it would depend on implementation, but you might end up with missing information.

The `Hashtable` on the other hand is synchronized and should be thread-safe.

Comment: There are better alternatives to the pre-historic `Hashtable`

Comment: Yep, a `ConcurrentHashMap` for example.

Answer (score -1):

Are you really mean a deadlock or maybe an endless loop? When using an unsynchronized `HashMap` in a mutithreaded environment multiple modifications can create an internally currupted hash map structure. Use `Collections.synchronizedMap()` to avoid this.

Answer (score -1):

`HashMap` is not thread-safe. To make `HashMap` thread-safe, utilize `Collections.synchronizedMap()` method.

```
HashMap<K, V> map = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<K, V>());
```